# IntelliJ and WebStorm treating npm linked local module as an indirect dependency, and not using it in it's suggestions

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, node-modules, webstorm, npm-link

I have a local node module I am trying to reuse in my other modules.

I use npm link to add the module as a dependency to other modules.

Everything works fine, however IntelliJ Treats this as an indirect dependency even if I add the dependency to the pom. Because of this none of the autocompletions for the dependency work.

[image]

Pom1:

```
{
  "name": "test-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"Module functionality testing project\"",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "\"No Tests done\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

pom2:

```
{
  "name": "test-module-2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "\"Module functionality testing project\"",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node index.js",
    "test": "\"No Tests done\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "test-module": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is tracked at [WEB-49242](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49242), please follow it for updates.
As a workaround, please try including `node_modules\test-module` folder in index by selecting **Mark directory as/Cancel exclusion** from its right-click menu

Comment: Thanks for the answer. unmarking it from exclusion still doesn't make it work with auto imports unfortunately. It doesn't see them

Comment: Tried this in WebStorm 2022.1.3 and now imports are working again. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend to re-exclude the `node_modules` forlder of the linked package

Comment: It's Feb 2024, the issue is still happening, but the solution "Mark directory as" -> "Not excluded" works!